# OCaml: applying second argument first(higher-order functions)

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, readability, higher-order-functions

I defined a higher-order function like this:

```
val func : int -> string -> unit
```

I would like to use this function in two ways:

```
other_func (func 5)
some_other_func (fun x -> func x "abc")
```

i.e., by making functions with one of the arguments already defined. However, the second usage is less concise and readable than the first one. Is there a more readable way to pass the second argument to make another function?

Comment: `other_func` and `some_other_func` are the higher-order functions (they operate over other functions), not `func`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Haskell, there's a function `flip` for this. You can define it yourself:

```
let flip f x y = f y x
```

Then you can say:

```
other_func (func 5)
third_func (flip func "abc")
```

Flip is defined in Jane Street Core as `Fn.flip`. It's defined in OCaml Batteries Included as `BatPervasives.flip`. (In other words, everybody agrees this is a useful function.)

Answer (score 0):

The question posed in the headline *"change order of parameters"* is already answered. But I am reading your description as "how do I write a new function with the second parameter fixed". So I will answer this simple question with an ocaml toplevel protocol:

```
# let func i s = if i < 1 then print_endline "Counter error."
    else for ix = 1 to i do print_endline s done;;
val func : int -> string -> unit = <fun>
# func 3 "hi";;
hi
hi
hi
- : unit = ()
# let f1 n = func n "curried second param";;
val f1 : int -> unit = <fun>
# f1 4;;
curried second param
curried second param
curried second param
curried second param
- : unit = ()
#
```